# Timestamp milliseconds format in mysql and python

Tags: python, mysql, timestamp, relational-database, singlestore

i have a simulator python which send the data to memsql, i'm trying to save timestamp in a column but it gives me an error

```
 Incorrect datetime value: '1530181024560' for column 'event_time' at row
```

here is my code python i generate event_time like that format: 1530181024560

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

 now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
 epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc) # use POSIX epoch
 posix_timestamp_micros = (now - epoch) // timedelta(microseconds=1)
 event_time = lambda:str(posix_timestamp_micros // 1000)
```

i tried datetime(3) and timestamp(3) but no way.

Answer (score 0):

the solution that i applied is to save the timestamp as a BigInt in the database then when i extract the data in spark(the case for me) i cast the value to timestamp with the : evenTime.cast(TimestampType)